# Applying for Two Student Visa

Tags: visas, germany, study

I have a strange question :) Can I apply for a student visa to two different EU countries? I got an admission offer from Dublin University, and semester begins on August last week. But I am waiting for an admission from a German public University. Since the German University course begins only in October, they didn't announce results by this month.

So, I am planning to apply an Ireland student visa now, later on if get an admission, is it possible to apply for a German visa? Did German Embassy rejects my application if I have a valid student visa for other country?

Comment: They probably won't reject it for that reason, but this question belongs on [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: Yes, you may apply for student visas simultaneously as they are issued by the individual member states. No problem.  I am on the same page as @phoog so close voting in favour of Expats.